# Python Appending dictionary in Loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have several netCDF data files with the same variables.  I want to read in multiple data files and store all of the data in a giant dictionary.  The problem with my code is that I can append the new dictionary, however, I can no longer separate the elements within the dictionary. For example:

```
def parseFile(file_name):
    ret_dict = {}
    with Dataset(file_name,'r') as fid:
        ret_dict['time'] = list(fid.variables['time'][:])
```

If I call this function for one data file, I might have:

```
>>> ret_dict['time'] 
[1,2,3,4]
```

for the second file, I might expect:

```
>>> ret_dict['time'] 
[5,6,7,8]
```

Within a loop I would like to create another dictionary with all of the values:

```
>>> new_dict['time']
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
new_dict = {}
for f in file_name:
    ret_dict = parseFile(f)
    new_dict.setdefault('time',[]).append(ret_dict['time'])
```

This yields:

```
>>> new_dict['time']
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

and

```
>>> new_dict['time'][0] 
[1,2,3,4]
```

I want:

```
>>> new_dict['time'][0]
[1]
```

I thought about appending new_dict in a loop, however, the data files are large, and that takes a while.  Is there a faster way to append dictionaries while still allowing the individual values to be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're appending lists to a list, creating a nested list, which is not what you want.

```
>>> ls = []
>>> ls.append([1, 2, 3])
>>> ls
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> ls[0]
[1, 2, 3]
```

There is, however, another method to add items to a list. It's called `.extend`

```
>>> ls = []
>>> ls.extend([1, 2, 3])
>>> ls
[1, 2, 3]
>>> ls[0]
1
```

Use this when you're adding the list like so:

```
new_dict = {}
for f in file_name:
    ret_dict = parseFile(f)
    new_dict.set_default('time',[]).extend(ret_dict['time'])
```

This will produce the expected list which you can easily index

By the way, your code will not work because there's no such method as `set_default` defined for dicts. You probably meant `setdefault`, which does what you want.